# Updating Product code

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I need to update the product code on the left of the image when the product options on the right change ?

[image]

Where would I need to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're looking for, but try this block

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
```

you can find it in : `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`